# SurfaceView is empty, not drawing object on canvas

Tags: android, surfaceview

I don't know why but my surface view is empty black screen. It should have red background.

What have I been wrong?

**SurfaceView**:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private GameThread gameThread;

    public GameView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        gameThread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        Utils.logI("Surface changed!");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Utils.logI("Surface created !");
        gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Utils.logI("Surface destroyed");
        boolean retry = true;

        gameThread.stopThread();

        while(retry)
        {
            try
            {
                gameThread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

**GameThread**:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean isQutting = false;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameView gameView;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView gameView)
    {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gameView = gameView;

        setName("Game thread");
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Canvas canvas = null;

        while(!isQuitting())
        {

            try
            {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized (surfaceHolder)
                {
                    gameView.draw(canvas);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (canvas != null)
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isQuitting() { return this.isQutting; }

    public synchronized void stopThread()
    {
        this.isQutting = true;
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain**:

```
public class ActivityMain extends BaseFragmentActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }

}
```

Comment: see this example :-`http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/707993-how-to-draw-2d-object-in-android-with-a-canvas` also see this `http://cell0907.blogspot.com/2013/10/tutorial-for-drawing-in-android.html`

Comment: You are calling gameView.draw(canvas), but you only have a gameView.doDraw(canvas), your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I can't use onDraw, it's protected

Comment: If you put a `Log` call in `onDraw()`, do you see it firing?  On a totally unrelated note, your `isQutting()` needs synchronization as well.  You can actually drop "synchronized" from `stopThread()` and just declare `isQuitting` with `volatile`.